# How to fill in the foreign keys automatically while using forms?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create an evaluation system, these are the tables and their relationships. [image]

Basically, I want to choose which teacher to evaluate, then choose a subject, then proceed to the evaluation.

It can already store the values of TeacherId and SubjectCode into  the TeacherEval table with the use of comboboxes. I created a subform which contains the evaluation table and I put it in my main form but whenever I try to fill-up the form, it doesn't automatically fill in the evalCode of the TeacherEval table.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the input! Though, I am a bit confused as the Teacher and Evaluation table has many-to-many relationship, that's why I created another table(TeacherEval) to connect the two.

Answer (score 0):

The Evaluation table as designed is not necessary because it has a 1-to-1 relationship with TeacherEval. Just include its fields in TeacherEval table. Otherwise, your table design is backwards. The evalCode field in TeacherEval needs to be autonumber primary key field then evalCode in Evaluation would be integer field not an autonumber.

Hope there is a date field in Evaluation or put in TeacherEval.